# do we need to make copy of matrix before calling lapack subroutines

Tags: c, lapack

I am solving some problem whose intermediate steps need solving Ax=b linear system. I am planning to use lapack to solve it by using a subroutine like say, DGESV. However I found out that lapack coverts matrix "A" into "PLU" (some lower and upper matrix format). I want "A" to be intact for my future operations. Do I need to make its copy before sending it to lapack everytime ? Making copy of "b" is ok, but, if "A" is large then copying itself is time consuming. Is there a way to avoid it or some other function from lapack which avoids altering "A". Also, if copying is unavoidable, then is there an efficient way to achieve it ? I am using "C" as the programming language.

Comment: (1) If a function modifies a data structure, and you need to retain the original contents, then you need to copy it first (2) The time it takes to copy a matrix is inconsequential compared to the time it takes to solve a linear system involving that matrix.

Comment: Do you use the [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) function to copy the whole matrix at once? It can be more efficient than using a for loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that lapack has some extra input arguments to store the new information into some other matrix. Anyways, if it is not possible, then as Francis suggested; memcpy() is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

LAPACK usually tries to store the result ínside the input arguments but here you want A to be constant.

LAPACK also internally uses a work array. You can basically follow a similar route by reading off the original elements to a working array. From a fixed source maybe a file or just keep it in the memory, solve the problem get the coefficients then retrieve the original elements and place them in the same array inplace.

Comment: How to interact with work array ? Can you simplify your answer ?  Do you mean, copy A to some array, and then use that array. or something else ?

Comment: @user402940 I mean using one array and continuously updating it mimicking the internal WORK array of LAPACK routines.